# How to allow only specific software to be installed for Domain users in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have **Windows server 2012 R2** with more than 100 domain users ...I want to allow only specific software's to be installed without asking for **admin privilege**  for example Chrome , Firefox using **group policy** ...I remember during my work in one of the companies they give me a laptop without admin privilege  and chrome and firefox can be installed ...I don't know how this is happening ...I think  there is a company signature or vendor signature that allow this to happen and allow the software to by pass the admin right ...but I don't know how ?

Comment: No. This would be extremely difficult to do and I'm not aware of a built in mechanism for doing so. Once you remove someone's admin permissions (that's the first step) then they can only install software in their user context, rather than system context. Both Firefox and chrome support this and do not require admin permissions to be installed. The other option is a self service web portal that users can choose an application and a service or remote script installs the software for them.

Comment: @Appleoddity thanks ...what it the easier solution ?